# How can I tell if a C struct has a member in Perl XS?

Tags: perl, perl-xs

Is there an `ExtUtils::*` or `Module::Build` (or other) analog to Ruby's [`mkmf.have_struct_member`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/index.html)?

I'd like to do something like (in the manner of a *hints/* file):

```
....
if struct_has_member("msghdr", "msg_accrights") {
    $self->{CCFLAGS} = join(' ', $self->{CCFLAGS}, "-DTRY_ACCRIGHTS_NOT_CMSG");    
}
...
```

`Config.pm` doesn't track the specific information I'm looking for, and `ExtUtils::FindFunctions` didn't seem quite appropriate here...

Comment: You want to know if a struct in the C library contains a given member?  Like whether `tm.tm_gmtoff` exists in time.h?

Comment: @Schwern, yes.  In this peculiar case, whether `struct msghdr` has `msg_accrights` or not.

Comment: There's no pre-built Perl database for that AFAIK.  Usually you use ExtUtils::CBuilder to compile a test program.  There might be a CPAN module to do it, but its not built into MakeMaker or Module::Build.

Comment: Brilliant!  Put that in an answer and I'll give you, uh, a fractional rep boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is not built into either MakeMaker or Module::Build.  There might be a thing on CPAN to do it, but the usual way is to use ExtUtils::CBuilder to compile up a little test program and see if it runs.

```
use ExtUtils::CBuilder;

open my $fh, ">", "try.c" or die $!;
print $fh <<'END';
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    struct tm *test;
    long foo = test->tm_gmtoff;

    return 0;
}
END

close $fh;

$has{"tm.tm_gmtoff"} = 1 if
    eval { ExtUtils::CBuilder->new->compile(source => "try.c"); 1 };
```

Probably want to do that in a temp file and clean up after it, etc...

Comment: Don't test the value of `close`?

Comment: @Kinopiko Its not meant as a complete tutorial on safe Perl I/O. I think I can count the number of times I've had a bug because `close` failed on my left hand. These days I use autodie and it takes care of everything.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a wrapper around `ExtUtils::CBuilder` for doing "does this C code compile?" type tests in `Build.PL` or `Makefile.PL` scripts, called [ExtUtils::CChecker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aCChecker).

For example, you can easily test the above by:

```
use Module::Build;
use ExtUtils::CChecker;

my $cc = ExtUtils::CChecker->new;

$cc->try_compile_run(
    define => "TRY_ACCRIGHTS_NOT_CMSG",
    source => <<'EOF' );
      #include <sys/types.h>
      #include <sys/socket.h>
      int main(void) {
        struct msghdr cmsg;
        cmsg.msg_accrights = 0;
        return 0;
      }
EOF

$cc->new_module_build(
    configure_requires => { 'ExtUtils::CChecker' => 0 },
    ...
)->create_build_script;
```